# Pickle object : multithreading safe?

Tags: multithreading, pickle, python-3.5

I am using Python3.5.1, with threading module.

I saw lot's of Questions about writing in dictionary and Pickle file from several threads safely. In my case I want to read it and the question is:

Can I load (safely) a pickle file several times at the same time ?

Pseudo-Code:

```
import sys    
import threading
import pickle

def function_1( pickle_file, arg_blue ):
    my_dic = pickle.load( open( pickle_file, "rb" ) )
    # process my_dic with arg_blue

def function_2( pickle_file, arg_red ):
    my_dic = pickle.load( open( pickle_file, "rb" ) )
    # process my_dic with arg_red

def main( pickle_file, arg_blue, arg_red ):
    # Using two threads to call function_1 and function_2 at the same time.
    # Function 1 and function 2 will not exchange data. Is it better to use multiprocess module ?

    # thread_blue will run function_1
    # thread_red will run function_2
    # Each of them will write in a distinct output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main( sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3] )
```

Call of the script:

```
python3.5 my_script.py my_pickle_file.p blue red
```

Any suggestion or commentary will be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, reading a file from multiple threads or processes is safe, as long as you open the file in the thread -- i.e. don't pass the same open handle to multiple threads, that's bad.

Note that multithreading in Python may not actually help if you want to parallelise work due to the [global interpreter lock.](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock).