# How do I correctly run pyspark code in parallel using the map function

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm having trouble running the following code on an emr cluster as pyspark code. I'm essentially trying to create groups of data divided by 2 primary keys. Slices are each unique combination of the primary key columns, and full data is a data frame containing the whole data as a dataframe object. That object was built using sqlContext. The following is failing when run in parallel, complaining of a serialization error with the pickle library.  Specifically `_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects`

What is the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

```
def main(slices, fullData):
    jsons = slices.rdd.map(
         lambda i: handleSlices(i, fullData)).collect()  # Run in parallel
    # jsons = [handleSlices(i, fullData)
    #    for i in slices.collect()]  # run in serial
    return jsons

def handleSlices(row, fullData):
    entries = fullData.filter((col("fullData.vehicle_id") == row.vehicle_id)
                              & (col("fullData.start_time") == row.start_time)).select(
        "fullData.latitude", "fullData.longitude")

    folder = "/playback/" + row.vehicle_id + "/"
    fileName = folder + row.start_time.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "-")

    return (fileName, entries)
```

Comment: pickle has some issues when you want to run something in parallel. I have faced this in the past as well. check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39897394/pickle-object-multithreading-safe

Maybe Im wrong. But just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main issues in your code:

- Spark is natively parallel so you don't have to do something special to make it run in parallel
- when using `map`, the code is running in the executors and not the driver, which means you can't use a DataFrame or RDD reference in your function (they only work on the driver).

Assuming both slices and fullData are DataFrame, this implementation should work and give a parallel dataframe that you can process later

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def main(slices: DataFrame, fullData: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
   df = (fullData.join(slices, ["vehicle_id", "start_time"], "inner")
             .select("vehicle_id", "start_time", "latitude", "longitude")
             .withColumn("file_name", F.concat_ws("/",
                                                  F.lit("/playback"),
                                                  F.col("vehicle_id"),
                                                  F.regexp_replace(F.regexp_replace("start_time", " ", "_"), ":", "-")))
             .groupBy("file_name")
             .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("latitude","longitude")).alias("positions"))
   )
   return df
```